# Looking for empty polygons using GeoPandas

Tags: python, polygon, line, geopandas

I have a shapefile and I would like the exploded view with GeoPandas in several polygons, I cannot use ArcGIS and keep the polygons that have a given.

```py
import csv 
import glob
import time
import sys
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

gdf = gpd.read_file("dossier/essais.shp")

time.sleep(10)
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = gdf.total_bounds

lenght = 2065
wide = 3069

cols = list(range(int(np.floor(xmin)), int(np.ceil(xmax)), wide))
rows = list(range(int(np.floor(ymin)), int(np.ceil(ymax)), lenght))
rows.reverse()

polygons = []
for x in cols:
    for y in rows:
        polygons.append( Polygon([(x,y), (x+wide, y), (x+wide, y+lenght), (x, y+lenght)]) )

grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':polygons}, crs = gdf.crs.to_string())
grid.to_file("dossier/grid.shp")

#df4.head(1000).to_file("dossier/"+file)
gdf.to_file("dossier/grille.shp")
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "explode"? Do you mean "extract" the empty polygons?

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer indeed the purpose and to have the information if the polygon and empty or filled.

Comment: is **explode** means separate the individual areas ?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10):

```py
gdf = gpd.read_file("dossier/essais.shp")
gdf_merged_geom = gdf.unary_union

#
# other lines
#

grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':polygons}, crs=gdf.crs.to_string())

# add new CASE column
grid["CASE"] = "FILLED"

for index, polygon in grid.iterrows():
    if polygon.geometry.disjoint(gdf_merged_geom):
        grid.loc[index, "CASE"] = "EMPTY"

print(grid.head())

# OUTPUT
#           geometry      CASE
# 0 POLYGON ((282...    EMPTY
# 1 POLYGON ((282...    FILLED
# 2 POLYGON ((282...    FILLED
# 3 POLYGON ((282...    FILLED
# 4 POLYGON ((282...    FILLED
```

Sample data:

[image]

Result:

```
custom_draw(grid[grid["CASE"]=="EMPTY"].geometry)
# OR 
# grid[grid["CASE"]=="EMPTY"].plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Please use [unary_union](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union) instead of [cascaded_union](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union) as recommended in the Shapely manual (The unary union function can operate on different geometry types, not only polygons as is the case for the older cascaded union.)

Comment: @gene Done. Thank you. I misunderstood the note in the shapely manual.